# preg_replace change brackets and text

Tags: latex, brackets, preg-replace-callback

I have a text string in PHP:

```
$str = 'This is a simple \^{text}. It does not look well \_{styled}.';
```

What I want to do is to change the "\^{text}" and "_{styled}" using preg_replace to get html code like this

```
$str = 'This is a simple <sup>text<sup>. It does not look well <sub>styled</sub>.';
```

What I have done now is this:

```
function Translate($str)
{
   return preg_replace('/\\\\\^\{.*\}/i', '<sup>$1</sup>', $str);
}
echo Translate("this offer starts at \^{abc}");
```

This does not work properly with $1! In $0 the entire match is correct...
Is there someone who can help me with that? Regars!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Quick and dirty: $str = 'This is a simple \^{text}. It does not look well _{styled}.'; echo preg_replace('~(\\\^{)(.*?)(})~', '<sup>$2</sup>', $str); echo preg_replace('~(\\_{)(.*?)(})~', '<sub>$2</sub>', $str); Maybe someone has a better solution?